# fulltext search method didn't work

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

i tried to build a search engine in my php script using full text feature,but it didn't get any results.
steps i did:
i altered a 2 fileds to full text

```
ALTER TABLE stack_ask ADD FULLTEXT(q_title,q_body)
```

then i added some data

```
INSERT INTO articles (q_title,q_body) VALUES('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...');
```

then i made a variable to recieve a post data from input

```
$q_title=$db->real_escape_string($_POST['search_word']);
```

then the query:

```
SELECT * FROM stack_ask WHERE MATCH (q_title,q_body) AGAINST ('$q_title');
```

when i tried to search something like database it didn't give any result and output the following error:

```
call to amember function fetch_assoc on a non-object
```

what's the problem?

Comment: try to get the query and execute it directly on mysql and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mohamed amin,

> Make sure that q_title,q_body has indexing or not. Read this article
>   may it will be useful for you.

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html
```

Comment: that should be a comment not answer !

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty I don't have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: i checked them,both are full text,i used

show index from stack_ask

Comment: Try this one `SELECT * FROM stack_ask where MATCH(q_title,q_body) AGAINST ('$q_title')  ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 0):

after multiple trials,i solved the problem by the following:
1-i checked the index type of 2 columns using the following sql:

```
show index from stack_ask
```

and they were full text

2-i checked the table type ,which was MYISAM

2-the correct sql query should be like the following:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(q_title,q_body) AGAINST ('$q_title') FROM stack_ask ORDER BY id DESC
```

not:

```
"SELECT id, MATCH(q_title,q_body) AGAINST ('$q_title') FROM stack_ask ORDER BY id DESC
```